# Run multiple commands in a single batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

```
(drush cc all) && (drush sql-dump --result-file=%backupdir%/%tarname%)
```

The above is executed but not the below command.

Can I run the below command using '&&' as well?

```
echo user username> ftpcmd.dat 
echo password>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put %backupdir%/%tarname% /Backup/%tarname%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftpserver
del ftpcmd.dat
```

I just need the ftp commands to execute after a successful database dump.

Thanks.

Comment: I have even tried running ftp details by saving the info in a separate file. After getting a database dump, still the code exits and ftp details are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You have not indicated what `drush` is, but probably it is a `.bat` or `.cmd` file. When a batch file invokes another batch file execution flow is transfered to the called one, but does not return to the caller.

You need to use `call drush ...`. The `call` command will return execution flow to the caller when the called one has ended